# stop selenium from creating new firefox profile every launch

Tags: python, selenium, yaml, firefox-profile

I am using `selenium` and `yaml` from a code got from a friend that creates a new Firefox profile every launch and I want to use my own profile, not a new profile

This is part of the code and i have been searching and trying everything to fix the problem but I couldn't figure out what to do more:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import yaml
import os

with open("assets/config.yaml", "r") as config:
    config = yaml.safe_load(config)

options = Options()
if config.get("settings").get("headless"):
    options.headless = True

    profile = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=config.get("settings").get("firefox"), service_log_path=os.path.devnull if not config.get("settings").get("log") else config.get("settings").get("log"), options=options)
```

And this is the code from config.yaml:

```
settings:
  headless: False
  firefox: assets/geckodriver.exe
  log: null
```

Comment: Can you post `config.yaml`?

Comment: i edited the post and add it

Comment: I just ran your code, but nothing happened...

Comment: i posted part of the code that concerned with firefox profie not full script code

Comment: the full code is working good , my only proplem that i want to use my own firefox profile not new profile every launch

Answer (score 0):

I've used it with Java, so in general maybe you can follow this steps:

1. Create a profile with `Firefox.exe -p` which creates it in the "C:\Users\xUser\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles" as `xyz.Selenium`.
2. There should be a `FirefoxProfile` class in the Python binding.
3. Pass that file to that class and use the profile object in the driver object.

Comment: tried and not working because the code is comibination between selenium and yaml in python not only selenium

Comment: Could you please check the properties in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Capabilities/firefoxOptions. I think you can apply the related `profile` property in config file.